# Table Partitioning. What is the correct process for deleting .ndf and .ldf files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please go easy it’s a steep learn curve..

OK steps done so far

1. Create files,
2. Create file groups,
3. Create partition function,
4. Create partition scheme,
5. Partition table associate files with filegroups
6. Put data in the table.

All is good

Now to reverse

The drop data

1. Drop the partition and associations,
2. Drop partition scheme,
3. Drop partition function,
4. Drop file groups

But when I deleted the files from the folder in my SSMS, I than had problems validating my Databases.

I restored the files and SSMS is fine.

My question **what is the correct process for deleting .ndf  and .ldf files?**

Comment: Describe more specifically what do you mean by "had problems validating my Databases".

Comment: The indivdual databases failed to display in SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete the LDF file: it's essential.

For the NDF, you need to show that it's not used to SQL Server. You'd use [DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) with EMPTYFILE. Substitute xxx based on [sys.database_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx)

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (xx, EMPTYFILE)
```

Comment: I created few Ldf files as well what is the best way to remove these.?